# Spotlight does not find file

Tags: spotlight

I have the file Rprofile.site in /Macintosh HD/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/

Searching 'Rprofile.site' in Spotlight does not find the file, and I have to manually go to the folder containing the file.

I'm on a Mac book pro using 10.8.2

Is there a way I can find the file using Spotlight?

Comment: Apparently not. There used to be a way to add folders to the Spotlight index using `mdimport -f` but that feature "has been obsoleted, and does nothing" in 10.5 and later. It is easy to exclude folders from Spotlight's index, but apparently impossible to force Spotlight to include specific folders.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is some folders are intentionally left out from the global spotlight search on the menubar.

For example, `/Library` and `/Users/*/Library`, one of the ways to search in these directories is to navigate to these directory in Finder, and search in the Spotlight field in the upper-right corner.

Comment: Is there any way of choosing which folders are included in spotlight search?

Comment: By making a Saved Search - which you can then drag to the Finder Sidebar if wanted. Or download the free and excellent EasyFind from DevonTechnologies, which will find anything anywhere.